# osclass showing category instead of item title

Tags: php, .htaccess, osclass

I'm using osclass I create the Permalinks of Listing URL to be

> {CATEGORIES}/{ITEM_TITLE}{ITEM_ID}

but my problem is the url now is displaying `category/categoryid` instead of returning `category/item_titleid`

**example:** instead of displaying `127.0.0.1/books/themagicbook4` is displaying 127.0.0.1/books/books4
if I hover the item is showing that the url is 127.0.0.1/books/themagicbook4 but when I click on it it redirect to `127.0.0.1/books/themagicbook4`

Comment: Sorry, but you forgot to describe your actual situation. What is your framework? Please invest time into revising the question. There is an "edit" link below your question, _use it_ . Try to read the question with our eyes, consider that we have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @arkascha I don't understand your comment I already mentioned that I'm using osclass